# Allow access to folder only from specific IP Address (or domain) and Port using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to secure access to a PHP page in a folder and only allow access to it from a specific IP Address and domain name but only on a specific port. I have seen a number of questions here but not including the PORT access.

I have added the following in the .htaccess file within the folder.

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.44:12345
```

However, this seems to be invalid.

What would be the correct way of doing it?

Comment: You maybe could use %{SERVER_PORT} ! port_number but honestly, it doesn't feel like the responsibility of htaccess to micromanage ports. You could perhaps use iptables for this instead.

Comment: I think you could use Require command with port number: Require expr %{SERVER_PORT} == 12345